# Pass the long and lat by GPS to other activity

Tags: android, location

Friends i have made a location based application.

i have implemented all the code and when my location is changed it calls onLocationChanged method of LocationListener Interface.

I have also used onUpdateLocation() method to get location updates and now i want to pass the lat and long to the activity. How can i do that ??

**UPDATED**

I know to use Intent . But where should i call the Intent?

I can not call it in onLocationChanged Mthod/

Please Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to create broadcast receiver inside of the activity. The LocationListener broadcasts a message each time a location is updated. Inside of this message you can put lat and lon values.

Using this way you can update the values dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(YourActivity.this, YourDestinationActivity.class);
intent.putDoubleExtra("com.example.lat", yourLatValue);
intent.putDoubleExtra("com.example.long", yourLongValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then use

```
Double d = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("com.example.lat", -1);
```

in YourDestinationActivity

Answer (score 0):

Using Broadcast is much better way, because location info and activities needs to be loosely coupled and passing such data async is safer.